# Handling null value of Class.SelectedItem.Value

Tags: .net, null

I've got the following code which is a click-event for a button:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    CheckBoxList cbl = btn.Parent.FindControl("chkbx_list") as CheckBoxList;
            
    if (cbl.SelectedItem.Value != null) //***Exception is thrown here***
    {
    //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

How can I check to see if the value in cbl.SelectedItem.Value is null? The moment that I try to "reference" the value, the application throws the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.SelectedItem.get returned null.
```

Comment: Do a null check then. Also, it may be null because of either the cast or the find control is actually returning null, possibly making this an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I can confirm that the cast of the actual web control does not return null. When you say to do a null check - isn't that what I'm doing with "if (cbl.SelectedItem.Value != null)" ? Or is there a different kind of "null check" that I am not familiar with?

Comment: The problem is that `SelectedItem` is null and you are tryin to access a member from a null instance. check that the member to access is not null first `if (cbl.SelectedItem != null && cbl.SelectedItem.Value != null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception message, the problem is that `SelectedItem` is *null* and you are trying to access a member from that null instance.

Check that the member to access is not null first to avoid null reference exceptions.

Here is the verbose approach

```
if (cbl.SelectedItem != null && cbl.SelectedItem.Value != null)
```

or using [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

```
if (cbl?.SelectedItem?.Value != null)
```

Comment: I think this makes sense. So if SelectedItem is null (and null is still a "value"), then SelectedItem.Value is not null; rather, it simply *does not exist*. Is that correct?

Comment: If `SelectedItem` is `null` then trying to access any of its members, (in this case `.Value`) means you are trying to access a value from a null reference, (which is not allowed by default in OOP) hence the exception (NullReferenceException)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are trying to use toString() method on a null object before you check whether it is null or not.
you need to Check the parent object value first.

as I cannot comment, I should change my answer as you change your problem.when you use as keyword for casting objects, it may return null if cast was a failure, check **cbl** value first to see if it is null or not.

Comment: I mistyped my code in the question and have now corrected it. I get the same error even without the ToString() method call.

Comment: I can confirm that the CheckboxList "cbl" does exist. I added in a similar line with a fake web control name like this:

CheckBoxList cbl = btn.Parent.FindControl("chkbx_list123456789") as CheckBoxList;

The fake name did return a null value, but the real name works.

Comment: since the cbl is not a null object, it seems that Nkosi's solution is right. @Jake